# Action Mailer to all Users not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

Generated a mailer to notify all users when an "article was created".  Had it working, now it stopped...not sure what happened.

Here's the actionmailer:

```
class ArticleMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: "Coach@gmail.com"


  # Subject can be set in your I18n file at config/locales/en.yml
  # with the following lookup:
  #
  #   en.referral_mailer.referral_confirmation.subject
  #
  def article_confirmation(user,article)
    @user = user 
    @article = article 
    mail to: user.email, subject: "Coach #{user.first_name}, a new goal has been posted"
  end
end
```

The controller with the call to to the mailer:

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController

  load_and_authorize_resource
  skip_authorize_resource :only => [:index, :show]

def new
    @article = Article.new
end

    def create
        @article = Article.new(article_params)
    #  authorize! :create, @article

        if @article.save
        #send email to referral email
        all_users = User.all
        all_users.each do |user|
          ArticleMailer.article_confirmation(user,@article).deliver
       end 
       redirect_to @article
        else
         render 'new'
        end
    end
.....
```

Comment: Can you post logs when you create a new article and try to send this email?

Comment: Try using `deliver!` see if it throws any errors.

Comment: Logs are here: http://pastebin.com/aDft32Ep

Comment: @Nitish no errors when I add the bang

Comment: The issue is that I can't find the controller for the rails admin?  Where can I modify the rails admin Article controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it's working with this added to the application controller:

```
before_action do  
    resource = controller_name.singularize.to_sym
    method = "article_params"
    params[resource] &&= send(method) if respond_to?(method, true)
end
```

Now...not working on admin side with rails_admin gem...